# Azure Web Role with Transient Fault Handling Block exception: The path is too long after being fully qualified

Tags: asp.net, azure, enterprise-library, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

We applied Transient Fault Handling Block for our web role of cloud service, we even didn't write one single line code. When we try to debug our cloud service locally, the exception would show on webpage, like this:

> The path is too long after being fully qualified.  Make sure the full
>   path is less than 260 characters and the directory name is less than
>   248 characters.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: The path is too long
>   after being fully qualified.  Make sure the full path is less than 260
>   characters and the directory name is less than 248 characters.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus' could not be loaded.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/AzureCloudService2/WebRole1/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\AzureCloudService2\WebRole1\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\AzureCloudService2\WebRole1\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/7f758b78-aef1-47f7-ad86-8be56d4218e0/temp/temp/RoleTemp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/63defe93/23a6bb89/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/7f758b78-aef1-47f7-ad86-8be56d4218e0/temp/temp/RoleTemp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/63defe93/23a6bb89/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/AzureCloudService2/WebRole1/bin/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\AzureCloudService2\WebRole1\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007006f). Probing terminated.
```

From the logging, it seems couldn't find `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus.dll` in above locations, but actually it indeed located at `C:/AzureCloudService2/WebRole1/bin/`, I've checked it many times.

Several information:

- We just install the packages via Nuget
- We also tried other packages such as `TransientFaultHandling.Caching` .etc, all have such problems.
- What's interesting is it works fine in worker role

Comment: It looks like the ASP.NET temporary directory is exceeding the max path length.  Take a look at [Windows Azure - Resolving 'The Path is too long after being fully qualified Error Message'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/14/windows-azure-path-too-long.aspx) to set the _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY environment variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@RandyLevy thanks for your comment, it solved my problem. You would win the bounty if you post it as an answer :)

> It looks like the ASP.NET temporary directory is exceeding the max
>   path length. Take a look at [Windows Azure - Resolving 'The Path is
>   too long after being fully qualified Error Message'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/14/windows-azure-path-too-long.aspx) to set the
>   `_CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY` environment variable. –  Randy Levy